# Highcharts - In area chart how to use gradient color for multiple series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Expect**
every series area has different gradient color.

**Tried**
I have read through the Highcharts demos, get know how to fill one area series with gradient color:

```
fillColor: {
  liearGradient: {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
  stops: [0, 'red'],
         [1, 'white']
}
```

but, I dont have any idea how to set different gradient color for each series area.

Because of my poor English, I upload two picture to make my question clear, and the right is the result I expected.

[image: Screen Shot 2016-12-26 at 2.21.24 PM.png]
[image: Screen Shot 2016-12-26 at 2.22.05 PM.png]

**Update**:
Thanks for @Alex Denisov, each series has different linearGradient color, but now The question is the point is under the color, especially the last one.

In one word, is it any possible to set linearGradient color each series independent, no cover.

[image: 1.png]

**Update**: https://jsfiddle.net/TabGre/fyxqsq4L/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would include the `fillColor` for each series with the `series` data like so:

```
plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },

series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268],
        lineWidth: 3,
        lineColor: 'rgba(58, 204, 188, 1)',
        marker: {
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColor: 'rgba(58, 204, 188, 1)',
          fillColor: 'rgba(58, 204, 188, 1)'
        },
        fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgba(58, 204, 188, 1)'],
                [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,.25)']
            ]
        },
    }, {
        name: 'Series 2',
        data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766],
        lineWidth: 3,
        lineColor: 'rgba(247, 106, 1, 1)',
        marker: {
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColor: 'rgba(247, 106, 1, 1)',
          fillColor: 'rgba(247, 106, 1, 1)',
          symbol: 'circle'
        },
        fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgba(247, 106, 1, 1)'],
                [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,.25)']
            ]
        },
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but now I think I should dig deeply to understand the value of `linearGradient' and what's the best opacity to set

Comment: Edited my code slightly to allow line and point attributes to be styled independently for each series, here's a working JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/23w97oLe/2/ - regarding the 'cover,' could you share a JSFiddle of the code you are working with?

Comment: Well done, is the key the area 'stacking' equal 'normal'  to achieve this?

Comment: In this case, specifying plotOptions is optional as the defaults work fine. Here's more on plotOptions.area.stacking: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.stacking